# create consecutive integer and then create index to a table stored in sqlserver using dplyr

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr

I am doing some data processing of some large tables stored in sqlserver that creating an index sometimes reduce the time needed for some R script to run. I try to use the `mutate` function of `dplyr` to create a new column (`idx`) with consecutive number, then use that `idx`column as index. But the mutate function seems not working and constantly give me this error:

```
> tbl(channel,'tbl_iris') %>% mutate(idx=1:n())
Error in from:to : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In 1:n() : NAs introduced by coercion\
```

Right now I am doing something that seems quite stupid to me like this, to "bypass" the above error message:

```
iris <- tbl(channel,'tbl_iris') %>% 
  collect %>%
  mutate(idx=1:n())

try(db_drop_table(channel,'##iris'))
copy_to(channel,iris,'##iris',temporary=FALSE)
db_create_index(channel,'##iris',columns='idx')
```

Is there any better way of doing this? Thanks!

### Update 01

I tried `mutate(idx = row_number())` as suggested by @Phil, it is not working and show the following error message:

```
> tbl(channel,'##iris') %>%
+   mutate(idx=row_number())
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT  TOP 10 "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species", row_number() OVER () AS "idx"
FROM "##iris"'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY. 
> tbl(channel,'##iris') %>%
+   arrange(Species) %>%
+   mutate(idx=row_number())
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT  TOP 10 "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species", row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "Species") AS "idx"
FROM (SELECT *
FROM "##iris"
ORDER BY "Species") "kwtundzona"'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

### Update 02

I tried the way suggested by @Moody_Mudskipper, and it seems working

```
> try(db_drop_table(channel,'##iris'))
[1] 0
> copy_to(channel,iris,'##iris',temporary=FALSE)
> tbl(channel,'##iris') %>% head(.,1)
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 5]
# Database: Microsoft SQL Server 11.00.6251[dbo@WCDCHCMS9999\CMSAH_DC7_999/data_xx_yyy]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  
1         5.10        3.50         1.40       0.200 setosa 
> 
> DBI::dbSendQuery(channel,"ALTER TABLE ##iris ADD idx INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL")
<OdbcResult>
  SQL  ALTER TABLE ##iris ADD idx INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
  ROWS Fetched: 0 [complete]
       Changed: 0
> db_create_index(channel,'##iris',columns='idx')
[1] 0
Warning message:
In new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : Cancelling previous query
> tbl(channel,'##iris') %>% head(.,5)
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 6]
# Database: Microsoft SQL Server 11.00.6251[dbo@WCDCHCMS9999\CMSAH_DC7_999/data_xx_yyy]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   idx
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>   <int>
1         5.10        3.50         1.40       0.200 setosa      1
2         4.90        3.00         1.40       0.200 setosa      2
3         4.70        3.20         1.30       0.200 setosa      3
4         4.60        3.10         1.50       0.200 setosa      4
5         5.00        3.60         1.40       0.200 setosa      5
```

I will try to modify my script to see if this gives similar performance boost when compared to my previous more silly method.

Other than the error message shown as below, I hope things are working as planned.

```
Warning message:
In new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : Cancelling previous query
```

Comment: Try `mutate(idx = row_number())`

Comment: I don't know about your case, but I would often have an auto-increment ID in the table and use a stored procedure to insert data, which would then give me back the ID of the appended row.

Comment: Is your wish to actually add the column to the remote table in the DB on the fly, using `mutate`? I think that's a wrong expectation, as you can see from your **Update 01**, `dbplyr` is typically trying to generate SELECT statements. Maybe you'd like to use `compute` instead of `collect`

Comment: Your tbl objet is a remote table, and you are trying with mutate to apply something that is for local objects ... It is likely that dplyr is designed to avoid the modification of the data  source .. so you may have to use another package for modifying the remote table

Comment: I cannot test this unfortunately, but try this: `DBI::dbSendQuery(channel,"ALTER TABLE tbl_iris ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL")` Then `DBI::dbSendQuery(channel,"CREATE INDEX id ON tbl_iris (id);")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge you can't add a column to an existing table on server side with `dbplyr` but for a simple query like this it is just as easy to use `DBI::dbSendQuery` for the desired effect. The following line will create an id column:

```
DBI::dbSendQuery(channel, "ALTER TABLE tbl_iris ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL")
```

Then you can create the index by using `dplyr::db_create_index` or send another query :

```
 DBI::dbSendQuery(channel, "CREATE INDEX id ON tbl_iris (id);")
```

Comment: @Mood_Mudskipper I have another questions of similar nature that I wonder if DBI can do similar trick, please see if you have any idea (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638350/modify-existing-and-copy-to-new-table-in-sqlserver-using-dplyr-without-using-col), thanks!